# Variable no longer accessible inside web sql transaction?

Tags: javascript, sql, web-sql

The function below is always returning 'Inserted serial: undefined'. I am struggling to realise why it is doing this, if I `console.log` before the db.transaction then it outputs a serial (just a number). Why is it that inside db.transaction data[i] is suddenly undefined?

```
  var localSerials = [340, 234, 545, 239, 546];

  function downloadUpdates(localSerials) {
    console.log("Updating local database...");
    $.getJSON("update.php", function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (localSerials.indexOf(data[i]) == -1) {
          db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO serials (serial) VALUES (' + data[i] + ')');
            console.log("Inserted serial: " + data[i]);
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your async transaction is inside the for loop, which cause creating many parallel transactions without reusing them. Put transaction outside of the loop and reuse the transaction for all request.

```
var localSerials = [340, 234, 545, 239, 546];

function downloadUpdates(localSerials) {
  console.log("Updating local database...");
  $.getJSON("update.php", function(data) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (localSerials.indexOf(data[i]) == -1) {
          tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO serials (serial) VALUES (' + data[i] + ')');
          console.log("Inserted serial: " + data[i]);
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```